# C# Datagridview last index out of bound

Tags: c#, datagridview, cells

hi guys im new here =)

i would need your help in a minimal troubble case, to save time for me =)

The problem is about that, i want to have datagridview Cells Values and
save the values to an array.

Up to now it works fine, but it just reads the first row cell and after
that process it just tells that the index is out of bound, but i dont understand why.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)     //wo soll er sich aufhalten -> zeilen
                {

                    **if (row.Cells[i].Value == null)**
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This row is empty");
                        break;
                    }
                        if (row.Cells[i].Value != null)
                        {
                            UnsortArray[i] = row.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                            MessageBox.Show(UnsortArray[i]);
                            ++i;
                        }

                }
```

Comment: What is "i". You are using a foreach loop to loop through all the rows.You need to loop through columns as well.

Comment: Because it tries to read `cell[length]` on the next row, which is out of bounds. Use two variables for index, one which you reset to 0 on every row.

Comment: Because i keeps getting bigger?

Comment: you want to store only one cell value in Array or all cell value ? In your code you mixup index 'i'. 'i' used as cell index as well as UnsortArray index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)   
                    {
                      for (int i=0; i<= dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
                        **if (row.Cells[i].Value == null)**
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("This row is empty");

                        }
                            if (row.Cells[i].Value != null)
                            {
                                UnsortArray[i] = row.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                                MessageBox.Show(UnsortArray[i]);

                            }

    }



                    }
```

also, I don't understand why would you want to do messageBox.show inside a loop. It should be out side the loop.

Comment: Why you increase i value in if (row.Cells[i].Value != null)
block? for loop already increasing i value.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)     //wo soll er sich aufhalten -> zeilen
                {

                    if (row.Cells[i].Value == null)
                        MessageBox.Show("This row is empty")
                    else
                        {
                            UnsortArray[i] = row.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                            MessageBox.Show(UnsortArray[i]);
                   //    ++i;  dont need to increment if you want to read only specific column
                        }
                }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem in the fastes possible way =) I tried to vote up, but its not possible yet! Do it afterwards!

Comment: @Niko: I will do it on behalf of you now

Answer (score 1):

Try something like following code>>

```
for(int i=0;i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
                {

                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].cells[i].Value==null)**
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("This row is empty");
                        break;
                    }

                    else
                        {
                          UnsortArray[i] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].cells[i].Value.ToString();
                            MessageBox.Show(UnsortArray[i]);

                        }





                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use different Index variable for `UnSortArray` (let say j). `i` is a index of cell which value you want to store in `UnSortArray`

**CODE**

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)     
            {

                if (row.Cells[i].Value == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This row is empty")
                }
                else
                    {
                        UnsortArray[j] = row.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show(UnsortArray[j]);
                        ++j;
                    }
            }
```